# How to specify model schema when referencing another dbt project as a package? (dbt multi-repo setup)

Tags: dbt

We're using a dbt multi-repo setup with different projects for different business areas. We have several projects, something like this:

- `dbt_dwh`
- `dbt_project1`
- `dbt_project2`

The `dbt_dwh` project contains models which we plan to reference in projects 1 and 2 (we have ~10 projects that would reference the `dbt_dwh` project) by way of installing git packages. Ideally, we'd like to be able to just reference the models in the `dbt_dwh` project (e.g.
`SELECT * FROM {{ ref('dbt_dwh', 'model_1') }}`). However, each of our projects sits in it's own database schema and this causes issue upon dbt run because dbt uses the target schema from dbt_project_x, where these objects don't exist. I've included example set-up info below, for clarity.

packages.yml file for `dbt_project1`:

```
packages:
  - git: https://git/repo/url/here/dbt_dwh.git
    revision: master
```

profiles.yml for `dbt_dwh`:

```
dbt_dwh:
  target: dwh_dev
  outputs:
    dwh_dev:
      <config rows here>
    dwh_prod:
      <config rows here>
```

profiles.yml for `dbt_project1`:

```
dbt_project1:
  target: project1_dev
  outputs:
    project1_dev:
      <config rows here>
    project1_prod:
      <config rows here>
```

sf_orders.sql in `dbt_dwh`:

```
{{
  config(
    materialized = 'table',
    alias = 'sf_orders'
    )
}}

SELECT * FROM {{ source('salesforce', 'orders') }} WHERE uid IS NOT NULL
```

revenue_model1.sql in `dbt_project1`:

```
{{
  config(
    materialized = 'table',
    alias = 'revenue_model1'
    )
}}

SELECT * FROM {{ ref('dbt_dwh', 'sf_orders') }}
```

My expectation here was that dbt would examine the `sf_orders` model and see that the default schema for the project it sits in (`dbt_dwh`) is `dwh_dev`, so it would construct the object reference as `dwh_dev.sf_orders`.

However, if you use command `dbt run -m revenue_model1` then the default dbt behaviour is to assume all models are located in the default target for `dbt_project1`, so you get something like:

```
11:05:03  1 of 1 START sql table model project1_dev.revenue_model1 .................... [RUN]
11:05:04  1 of 1 ERROR creating sql table model project1_dev.revenue_model1 ........... [ERROR in 0.89s]
11:05:05
11:05:05  Completed with 1 error and 0 warnings:
11:05:05  
11:05:05  Runtime Error in model revenue_model1 (folder\directory\revenue_model1.sql)
11:05:05    404 Not found: Table database_name.project1_dev.sf_orders was not found
```

I've got several questions here:

- How do you force dbt to use a specific schema on runtime when using dbt `ref` function?
- Is it possible to force dbt to use the default parameters/settings for models inside the `dbt_dwh` project when this Git repo is installed as a package in another project?

Some points to note:

- All objects & schemas listed above sit in the same database
- I know that many people recommend mono-repo set-up to avoid exactly this type of scenario, but switching to a mono-repo structure is not feasible right now, as we are already fully invested in multi-repo setup
- Although it would be feasible to create `source.yml` files in each of the dbt projects to reference the output objects of the `dbt_dwh` project, this feels like duplication of effort and could result in different versions of the same sources.yml file across projects
- I appreciate it is possible to hard-code the output `schema` in the dbt config block, but this removes our ability to test in dev environment/schema for `dbt_dwh` project

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution so I'll answer my own question in case anybody else runs up against the same issue. Unfortunately this is not documented anywhere that I can find, however, a throw-away comment in the dbt Slack workspace sparked an idea that allowed me to find the/a solution (I'll post the message if I manage to find it again, to give credit where it's due).

To fix this is actually very simple, you just need to add the project being imported to your `dbt_project.yml` file and specify the schema. For our use case this is fine as we only have 1 schema we use.

dbt_project.yml for dbt_project1:

```
models:
  db_project_1:
  outputs:
    project1_dev:
      <configs here>
    project1_prod:
      <configs here>
  dbt_dwh:
    +schema: [[schema you want these models to run into]]
    <configs here>
```

The advantages with this approach are:

- When you generate/serve dbt docs it allows you to see the upstream lineage from the upstream project
- If there are any upstream dependencies in your upstream project you can run this using dbt run -m +model_name (this can be super handy)

  - If you don't want this behaviour then you can use `dbt run -m +model_name --exclude dbt_dwh` (for example) to prevent models in your upstream project from running.

I haven't yet figured out if it is possible to use the default parameters/settings for models inside the upstream project (in this case `dbt_dwh`) but I will edit this answer if I find a way.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar use case as you. In our case, we could to explicitly define the `+schema` for the upstream packages instead of the downstream one. Something like this:

**dbt_dwh:**
`dbt_project.yml`

```yaml
models:
  dbt_dwh:
    marts:
      +schema: *[define these here]*
      ...
```

then in our downstream packages, we could simply use ref like:
`ref('dbt_dwh', 'mart_my_table')`

Of course, the answer from the original author also works.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue today.

After few hours reading and trying stuff I made it work by specifying the database (GCP project) in the config block in the first model (the one living in dbt_dwh project I guess).

It should look like this:

```
{{
  config(
    materialized = 'table',
    alias = 'sf_orders',
    database = 'dbt_dwh',
    schema = 'bq_dataset_name' # Not sure if this one is needed but worth trying
    )
}}
```

That worked for me. Maybe you can also try specifying the database in one of the schema.yml files or even the dbt_project.yml file or profiles.yml file.